# JSON response issues c#

Tags: c#, json, structure

I have to return a JSON string in a c# API which follows like:

`{
    "model" : 4 ,
    "lang" : "en_US",
    "parts" : 
         [
            {
                "id" : 1545,
                "name" : "Part 1",
                "part_types"  :
                    {
                        "type 1" :
                            {
                                "url" : "part.com/type1",
                                "desc" : "has 6 bits"
                            },
                        "type 2" :
                            {
                                "url" : "part.com/type2",
                                "desc" : "has 7 bits."
                            }
                    }
            }
        ]
}`

I have a basic structure like:

```
public class inventory
{
    public int model { get; set; }
    public string lang { get; set; }
    public part[] parts { get; set; }
}

public class part
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public type types { get; set; }
}

public class type
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string desc { get; set; }
}
```

but I keep receiving the output like:

`{
    "model" : 4 ,
    "lang" : "en_US",
    "parts" : 
         [
            {
                "id" : 1545,
                "name" : "Part 1",
                "part_types"  :
                    {
                            "url" : "part.com/type1",
                            "desc" : "has 6 bits"
                    }
            }
        ]
}`

I have 2 issues, one is when I run the API I can only display one type and if I try to make a List it adds [...] as in an array but I don't want an array I have to display a tittle for each type and then the details not in array form.

Second issue is under part_types I can not work out how to display the name of the part type before the details. If I try to add another class the name I set in the class is always displayed and I can not change it.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Visual Studio 2012 and Web Tools 2012.2 or later, then there is a feature called `Paste JSON As Classes` where you can paste your valid JSON into the code editor and select Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON As Classes to generate C# or VB.NET classes that will generate your pasted JSON structure.

Read [Paste JSON As Classes’ in ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/12/18/paste-json-as-classes-in-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-rc.aspx) for more information and instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following web site to autogenerate C# classes

http://json2csharp.com/

Few key points

1. Names of the classes don't matter but names of the identifiers matter.
2. Give valid Key names, you have spaces in JSON keys right now

**Edited Anwser**

If you are not sure which json is coming to you, You can use dynamic type of C#.

Install JSONConvertor from Nuget. (Right click on references of the project).

Then you can pass json string as follow.

```
dynamic output = JSONConvertor.Deserialize(inputString);
```

variables of dynamic types are bypassed by compiler so you can write

```
output.ANYNAMEYOULIKE
```

It will be resolved at runtime. Thats how you can check different JSONs using if else condition

Comment: Thanks for that, and I tried it out and received type1 and type2 as classes, but these ones need to be made depending on the types I get from the database, maybe one query be for type1, type3, type8, where another query might be type3, type7 etc, types need to be added depending on the query results.

Comment: Thank you are also right you can Desrialize to get the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers however I received another answer from another question which can answer this one.

follow [this questions to see answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827821/using-object-in-api-response)

Use:

```
public Dictionary<string, type> part_types { get; set; }
```