# Using object in API response

Tags: c#, api, response

I'm building a API that responds to GET requests. One field is a object and it needs to be repeated with data for as many times as the query returns.

Can anyone give me a example of how to use a object in a response with c#? Also the class need to be create?

Thanks in advance.

ADD:

so far I have a structure like:

```
public class root
{
public int model { get; set; }
public string lang { get; set; }
public part[] parts { get; set; }
}

public class part
{
public int id { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
public type part_types { get; set; }
}

public class type
{
public string url { get; set; }
public string desc { get; set; }
}
```

and the response coming back as

{ "model" : 4 , "lang" : "en_US", "parts" : [ { "id" : 1545, "name" : "Part 1", "part_types" : { "url" : "part.com/type1", "desc" : "has 6 bits" } } ] }

but I need it like

{ "model" : 4 , "lang" : "en_US", "parts" : [ { "id" : 1545, "name" : "Part 1", "part_types" : { "type 1" : { "url" : "part.com/type1", "desc" : "has 6 bits" }, "type 2" : { "url" : "part.com/type2", "desc" : "has 7 bits." } } } ] }

The part_type field is the object and I made a class called type. But I need to have one or many type and specify the name of the type eg "type 1" then have 2 more fields under it url and desc. As you can see above has 2 type, type 1 and type 2.

Can anyone help me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Since you are building this `API` can you show what you have thus far..? perhaps a code sample may help others to guide you in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly, you want "part_types" to be able to have many parts? In your current code, a part_types object can only have one.

You need two things:
1. A data type that is a collection, and
2. A serializer that writes that data type the way you want.
So, for example, you can use a Dictionary (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary).

```
public Dictionary<string,type> part_types { get; set; }
```

So, assuming you have created objects type1 and type2, you would write:

```
mypart.part_types = new Dictionary<string,type>();
mypart.part_types.Add("type 1", type1);
mypart.part_types.Add("type 2", type2);
```

Now what happens depends on the serializer. I typically use Json.NET, which works well and is free. I set up my objects like yours but using the dictionary, and I get:

```
{
  "model": 4,
  "lang": "en_US",
  "parts": [
    {
      "id": 1545,
      "name": "Part 1",
      "part_types": {
        "type 1": {
          "url": "part.com/type1",
          "desc": "has 6 bits"
        },
        "type 2": {
          "url": "part.com/type1",
          "desc": "has 6 bits"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I think that's what you're looking for... HOWEVER, using the DataContractJsonSerializer (System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer), I get this:

```
{
  "lang": "en_US",
  "model": 4,
  "parts": [
    {
      "id": 1545,
      "name": "Part 1",
      "part_types": [
        { "Key" : "type 1", "Value": {"desc":"has 6 bits","url":"part.com\/type1"} },
        { "Key" : "type 2", "Value": {"desc":"has 6 bits","url":"part.com\/type1"} }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm not sure how the DataContractJsonSerializer handles other collections (e.g. Lists, KeyValuePairs, etc.) so if you're using it, you may need to experiment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is there any other way to do it without making it into an array? As they specified to not have it in the array operators. eg so the type is not between "[" and "]" characters.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand better now. I edited my answer -- as I re-read it I noticed there was an inaccuracy in the original, anyway (I should've said an array of key-value pairs). But, I hope my revision is more helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I also found another way to fix it by making a JSON string on a loop then Deserialize the JSON to a object. But your way is far better thanks again.